# javascript regular expression match exclude space and special charcters

Tags: javascript, regex

Am having set of restricted keywords

in my comment / message posting block should not allow the restricted words which i defined.

Eg: keyword is "facebook".

f-a-c-e-b-o-o-k, FaceBook, f a c e b o o k, f*a*c*e*b*o*o*k, f a  c  e  b o  o  k, (face book),'facebook' these words should not allow to post.

Any ideas using regular expression in java script would be appreciated.

Comment: Required reading: [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "f*a*c*e*b*o*o*k"? Do you mean those characters with any characters in between? I can see this causing great difficulties.

"Looks like we'll have to face the books guys" - DENIED

Comment: @Evan Knowles - yes i meant any special character

Comment: @EvanKnowles OP didn't want to authorize "any characters".

Comment: You will have a better time assigning moderators to your site than you would actually blocking words. I would do both, but keep the regex's simple and the moderators can do the detective work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is a good idea but all the words you show could be detected using

```
var isFacebook = /f\W*a\W*c\W*e\W*b\W*o\W*o\W*k/i.test(str);
```

Note that you can easily generate such a pattern from a word, which makes it easy to extend with a dictionary :

```
var r = new RegExp("facebook".split('').join('\\W*'), 'i');
```

Comment: @thg435 You're right, I always forget this one, it's shorter. Thanks.

Comment: +1 never thought to create new regexp patterns by exploding the string into its individual characters.

Comment: You may want to add the word boundaries check to avoid the 'clbuttic' error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
f[^a-zA-Z0-9]?a[^a-zA-Z0-9]?c[^a-zA-Z0-9]?e[^a-zA-Z0-9]?b[^a-zA-Z0-9]?o[^a-zA-Z0-9]?o[^a-zA-Z0-9]?k
```

It will match the following:

```
facebook
f a c e b o o k
f-a-c-e-b-o-o-k
f*a*c*e*b*o*o*k
```

But will not match the following:

```
facesbooks
ffaceebbookss
```

You can use a regex similar to the one provided to detect such words.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to filter a given word, surrounded by word-boundary and with possible special characters separating the word's letters:

```
var keyword="facebook",
    specialCharClass="[*-]",
    regex;
regex= new RegExp("\\b" + keyword.replace(/(?:)/g,specialCharClass+'?') + "\\b",'g');

"hi(facebo-ok)pie".replace(regex,"__________"); //returns "hi(__________)pie"
```

However, there are always ways around word filters (faceb00k for example).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to block, not to strip, I would implement this as a two step process.

1. Strip out all non-text, translate 1337 to normal text (say leet), etc
2. check for forbidden words, and block if any go wrong

That way you seperated your concerns of blocking a certain list of words, and making sure that you're checking the actual text.